# How to make vendor_pull command work on Windows, specify path and commands in correct format

Tags: linux, windows, path

The problem is that the following command "vendor_pull" doesn't work on Windows. It can't find path somewhere, most likely due to wrong commands or etc.

```
  vendor_pull:
    - rd -r "src/static/vendor"
    - mkdir -p src/static/vendor/htmx/
    - mkdir -p src/static/vendor/flowbite/
    - curl -L https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.8.2 -o ./src/static/vendor/htmx/htmx.min.js
    - copy ./node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js ./src/static/vendor/flowbite/flowbite.min.js
```

All paths are correct here, since I copied it from tutorial, and have the same folder hierarchy and etc, but I need to make it work for Windows.

[This is the folder hyerarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ERb7.png)
Also if I change "rd -r" on "cmd" all exceptions disappear but the commands are still not being executed

Answer (score 0):

In Windows paths are separated by '' not '/', either you replace '/' with '' manually in the code or use `os.sep` to use the correct path separator on the current OS.

Comment: So basically change '/' on '\'? It doesn't work for some reason as well